# Unordered outcomes (counting)

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Suppose a social network has 20 users.

(a) How many pairs of users exist?
(b) In how many states can be the social network be assuming every pair of users can be in two states: friendship or no friendship.

For a, it's just 20 choose 2, which 190.

But I'm at a loss for how to approach the second question and I don't think it's as simple as $190 \times 2$. 380 would be the number of possible pairs of the 20 users assuming each pair can be labeled as either being friends or not friends.

Am I totally overthinking this problem? The system is exactly 10 pairs which each pair either being friends or not friends. So it boils down to how many possible ways to choose 10 pairs of  the 190, without repeating any users...

Comment: Hint: You have 190 pairs of users. Each pair can have 2 values independent of each other pair. How many values in total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If you have $n$ numbered marbles, in how many distinct ways can you paint some of them red and the rest blue? Now replace the marbles by pairs of users and the colors by ... ?